# Django REST framework APIの振り分け方法およびrest_framework_nestedの使用方法

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

urls.pyのurlpatternsの記述方法を教えてください。

例えば、以下のように、URLにつなぎ足すことで、処理を振り分けたいと考えています。
しかし、この記述方法であると、book/のみ認識され、すべてBookALLAPIViewに振り分けられてしまいます。
<book_key>にあたるURLを記述した場合、postmanで、最後に/が入らないとエラーだと判断されてしまいます。
一番下のpath('book/',...)のみ宣言した場合だど、最後に/の有無にかかわらず処理ができます。

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('version/',VersionAPIView.as_view()),
    path('book/<book_key>/price/<command>/',BookPriceAPIView.as_view()),
    path('book/<book_key>/price/',BookPriceAPIView.as_view()),
    path('book/<book_key>/＜command>/',BookAPIView.as_view()),
    path('book/<book_key>/',BookAPIView.as_view()),
    path('book/',BookALLAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

## DRFパッケージ

追加調査により、以下のパッケージが有効なようです。
[drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

### このパッケージの要件

Django: (2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0)
Python: (3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11)
Django REST framework: (3.11, 3.12, 3.13)

この要件に伴い、以下の環境にしました。
Django:4.0
Python:3.11
Django REST framework:3.13

本パッケージの正常な使用方法が分かればご教示ください。

Comment: import エラーの部分は解決したなら 「振り分け方法」の質問とは無関係なので削除するか、別の Q&A として切り分けた方が良さそうです。

Comment: 時期と扱っている版数がとても古いので参考になるか不明ですが、こんな記事があるようです。[Django REST frameworkのdrf-nested-routersで階層構造のURLを実装する](https://qiita.com/hfujima/items/fe8d4470a05895a70748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決できたようなので、投稿します。

drf-nested-routersパッケージを使用します。
この例では、modelsで定義したデータベースとリンクしない形でAPI応答する処理となっています。

## このパッケージの要件

Django: (2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0)
Python: (3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11)
Django REST framework: (3.11, 3.12, 3.13)

## フォルダ構成

api:rest framework用アプリケーション
app:WEBサーバー用アプリケーション
config:Djangoプロジェクト

フォルダツリー

```
.
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── api
│   │       └── version.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── app
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── test_models.py
│   │   └── test_models_handle.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

## ソースコード

config/urls.pyにおいて、urlパスを各アプリケーションに振り分ける。

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

api/urls.py
**registerで登録する順序が重要です。**

```py
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework_nested import routers
from .views import *

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('book/open', BookOpenViewSet, basename='book_open')
router.register('book/close', BookCloseViewSet, basename='book_close')
router.register('book', BookViewSet, basename='book')

book_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'book', lookup='book')
book_router.register(r'open', BookKeyOpenViewSet, basename='book_open')

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('v1/', include(book_router.urls)),
    path('version/', VersionView),
]
```

api/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

import json

from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.http import JsonResponse

def VersionView(request, *args,**kwargs):
    params = {
        'version':
            json.dumps({'version':'ver 1.2'},indent=2)
    }
    return render(request,"api/version.html",params)


class BookViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, requset):
        return JsonResponse({"book":"all book list"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        return JsonResponse({"book":f"book id = {pk}"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})

    def create(self, request):
        # POST
        return JsonResponse({"book":f"book create"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})

class BookOpenViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, requset):
        return JsonResponse({"book":"book open command"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})

class BookCloseViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, requset):
        return JsonResponse({"book":"book cloase command"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})

class BookKeyOpenViewSet(BookOpenViewSet):
    def list(self, request, book_pk=None):
        return JsonResponse({"book":f"book({book_pk}) open command"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})
    
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, book_pk=None):
        return JsonResponse({"book":f"book({book_pk}) open command({pk})"}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})
```

## URLパス

| url | response |
| --- | --- |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/version | { "version": "ver 1.2" } |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book | { "book": "all book list" } |
| [POST]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book/ | { "book": "book create" } |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book/1 | { "book": "book id = 1" } |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book/open | { "book": "book open command" } |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book/close | { "book": "book close command" } |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book/1/open | { "book": "book(1) open command" } |
| [GET]http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/book/1/open/2 | { "book": "book(1) open command(2)" } |

**注意：**
POSTコマンドの末尾`/`が必須です。
この理由がお分かりの方はコメントにて追加情報をいただけるとありがたいです。